# How many different ways are there to choose 6 donuts from the 21 varieties at a donut shop?

Tags: combinations

Can you help me to find out the solution of this problem and explain the answer?

Comment: What do you call a "variety" ? Do you mean plainly that there a 21 donuts ? But in this case, the result is not understandable.

Comment: @JeanMarie I mean different tests.

Comment: Sorry, but, in this case, what do you call a "test" ? I am pretty certain that something is missing in your question.

Comment: @JeanMarie I think he means taste

Comment: @JeanMarie It was an exam question ... the Q is correct ..

Comment: @JeanMarie I got it ... Thanks guys ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\binom{21+6-1}{6} = $230230
**Or** $\binom{21+6-1}{20} = $230230

Using *starts* and *bars* method:  For 21 varieties we need 20 bars for selecting the items. Then, we will have **(20+6)** or **(21+6-1)** choices '6' stars or (donuts) and '20' to separate the different kinds of donuts (as in the Q: **Varieties**) as shown below:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  _ _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

Or: `|**|*|** ..... *|*`

And from these options we can either select the **6** donuts "Starts"
 or, the **20** "Bars" which we use to separate between tests.

Comment: I am sorry, but this explains nothing.

Comment: This explains nothing and is wrong as it stands. (what means 230 230?)

Comment: @saturatedexpo Now?

Comment: *stars and bars, but thats only a typo i guess (even tho you use starts twice, so...). Much better then before, but i hope you yourself understand it too.